# UIButton addTarget Selector is not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

SquareBox.swift

```
class SquareBox {
  func createBoxes() {
    for _ in 0..<xy {
            let button = UIButton()

            button.backgroundColor = .white
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
            button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(sender:)) , for: .touchUpInside)
    }
  }

  @objc func click(sender : UIButton) {
    print("Click")
  }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let boxRow = SquareBox() 
        boxRow.createBoxes()
    }
}
```

Also I've tried @IBAction instead of @objc, it doesn't work, but if I use "click" function in ViewController.swift that I created this object, it's working but I need this function inside of this class.

Comment: Where is the button frame given? or Stack frame given

Comment: Show the code , how you called `createBoxes()` in your `ViewController.swift ` it will be clear then !

Comment: I put a stack view from story board, and I put my buttons inside of it.

Comment: Update your question with the code that creates the instance of `SquareBox` and calls the `createBoxes` method.

Comment: And clarify what you mean by "is not working". What is the exact, actual problem?

Comment: Are you serious? It's not the problem it's creating in it. 
I'm saying "there is no error but it's not working", if you don't understand that, the problem is on you? I wrote there print, so it's not printing to output.

Comment: @MuratSahin Your question does not state there is no error. Your question only states "is not working". That could mean many possible things. Programming requires you to be precise. How can anyone know what the real problem is if you don't put that information in your question? If you want people to be able to offer you good answers you must first provide a good, clear question. Make it easy for people to help you. And you still need to update your question with the code that creates your `SquareBox` and calls `createBoxes`. That is important information.

Comment: Is it OK, Mr Ruleman? @maddy

Comment: Yes, now that you've posted useful information, your question is easily answered. Instead of being rude to people trying to help you, you should actually provide useful details in your question when asked. Remember, you are the one asking the question. You are the one that doesn't know why your own code doesn't work. People here are volunteering their time to help you. Making it harder for them to help or being rude to them, is not going to be productive.

Comment: Please Mr @maddy I'm quite kind to the trying to help me as you can see at the below. I just don't understand people criticize some unnecessary things instead of helping. If you wanna help me, you could do that without other informations.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Now that you have posted relevant information in your question, the problem is quite clear. You have a memory management issue.

In your GameViewController's `viewDidLoad` you create a local instance of `SquareBox`. This local instance goes out of scope at the end of `viewDidLoad`. Since there is no other reference to this instance, it gets deallocated at the end of `viewDidLoad`.

Since the instance of `SquareBox` has been deallocated, it is not around to act as the button's target. And your `click` method is never called.

The solution is to keep a reference in your view controller:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
    let boxRow = SquareBox() 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        boxRow.createBoxes()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, concise answer. For more information, I suggest others read up on automatic reference counting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting.

Answer (score 7):

```
 var btnfirst:UIButton!
 override func viewDidLoad() 
 {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    btnfirst = UIButton(type: .system)
    btnfirst.setTitle("Press", for: .normal)
    btnfirst.setTitleColor(.red, for: .normal)
    btnfirst.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 100, height: 30)
    btnfirst.addTarget(self, action: #selector(benpress( sender:)),for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btnfirst)
}

func benpress( sender :UIButton) 
{
  //Your Code Here                       
}
```

Comment: I think it's in one of class that have extension ViewController, but I'm trying to do this in a class. Otherwise working bro :)

Answer (score 7):

For those who did not find a solution, here is mine.

If you constructed your `UIButton` as

```
let button: UIButton = {
  return UIButton()
}()
```

Just convert those into

```
lazy var button: UIButton = {
  return UIButton()
}()
```

I think this is because of somewhat deallocation as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.click), for: .touchUpInside)

func click(sender : UIButton) {
       // code here
    }
```

Comment: Said, "put @objc before the click func" I put, didn't work.

Comment: remove @objc, and try using . touchDown instead of . touchUpInside

Comment: I've changed to .touchDown and removed the @ objc but gave an error again wanted me to add @ objc when I accepted, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is how you are setting up layout of your buttons.
Try this:

```
func createBoxes() {
    stack.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    for _ in 0..<xy {
        // Create the button
        let button = UIButton()
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        // Add constraints
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44.0).isActive = true

        // Setup the button action
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SquareBox.click(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Add the button to the stack
        stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
}

@objc func click(sender : UIButton) {
    print("Click")
}
```

Comment: It's already inside of the stack view, I didn't think constraints are important. I tried these changes, but it didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

func buttonTapped(sender : UIButton) {
       // code here
    }
```

Comment: why you are using @objc it is simple code for button click

Comment: @objc is to make the #selector working.

Answer (score -2):

Replace with this :

```
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.click(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

[image]

I think something else effect to your selector method try to find in your code because your code also working in my project.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but gave an error, "Value of type 'SquareBox' has no member 'click'".

Comment: try my updated answer . i forgot to mention sender in selector .

Comment: It wanted "add @objc before the click func" I accepted and didn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why but not working, I wrote the same thing
Edit: there is no error but not working.

Comment: Yeah, maybe there is something else, because when I call the click method in ViewController.swift, it worked, but inside of the SquareBox.swift didn't.

Comment: Please don't post code as an image. Post code as actual text in your answer. Images can't be searched, copies, or referenced.

Comment: @maddy for eg. in here there is nothing that people find useful, because he just showed me the same code running at his computer. Your comment is totally unnecessary.