# Image Picker Controller delegate in separate class doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm new to Xcode and Swift. I'm currently playing around with [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/) tutorial by Apple.

Everything works fine so far, except one thing. The tutorial handles Image Picker delegate inside the main `ViewController` class, making it conform to `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` protocols. I wanted to try something else and move the delegate to separate class. Here's what I did:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class MealPhotoDelegate: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var placeholder: UIImageView?

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }

        placeholder!.image = selectedImage

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And in the `ViewController`:

```
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    let imagePickerDelegate = MealPhotoDelegate()
    imagePickerDelegate.placeholder = photoImageView

    imagePickerController.delegate = imagePickerDelegate

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Every time the Image Picker appears and when I navigate through the photos, the error is being generated:

> 2017-07-20 01:49:00.937470+0200 FoodTracker[41600:4236501] API error: (null) returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

What am I doing wrong? Is `UIViewController` good choice of a superclass for a delegate? I feel like maybe not.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158000/uibutton-addtarget-selector-is-not-working It's the same issue and solution, just with different classes.

Comment: @rmaddy Doesn't look "same" to me.

Comment: Did you read my answer to the question I linked? It's the same resolution.

Comment: No, it's not the same. It's not even a delegate for UI component.

Comment: It's just simple class usage in extended view. What does it have to do with my question? I'm not a programming newbie, but an Xcode newbie and I don't know how these particular elements are bound together.

Comment: See my answer below. Compare to the one I linked. Same issue, same solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is one of memory management. Inside your `selectImageFromPhotoLibrary` you create a local instance of `MealPhotoDelegate`. At the end of the method, this instance goes out of scope and gets deallocated because there is no strong reference to it. Therefore, the image picker's delegate becomes `nil` and it doesn't work.

The solution is to make a strong reference to the instance of `MealPhotoDelegate`. This is easily done using a property in your view controller class.

Add the following property to your view controller class:

```
var imagePickerDelegate: MealPhotoDelegate?
```

Then update the line:

```
let imagePickerDelegate = MealPhotoDelegate()
```

with:

```
imagePickerDelegate = MealPhotoDelegate()
```

That's it. It will work now.

As a side note, there is no reason why your `MealPhotoDelegate` should extend `UIViewController`. Make it extend `NSObject` instead. And you the fix the new issues by using the proper code.

Here's how it should be:

```
class MealPhotoDelegate: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var placeholder: UIImageView?

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }

        if let placeholder = placeholder {
            placeholder.image = selectedImage
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it tomorrow.

Comment: It made it work, but the 0 width error is still there. What can be the cause of it?

Comment: The "0 width" error isn't coming from your own code. Is there any other issue besides the appearance of that message?

Comment: Nope, other than that it all works. I'd like to get rid of this error though.

Comment: It's nothing with your code. What version of iOS? Do you see it on other devices/simulators?

Comment: I just used your code for a similar problem and it solved the issue, thanks a lot!!