# UIStepper won't register any event

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistepper

I'm adding a UIStepper to a horizontal UIStackView which itself is on a vertical UIStackView. The problem is that no matter what I do, the UIStepper won't register any event.

My code is the following

```
init(variableIndex: Int, variableName: String, withParentView parent: UIView, currentValue: String, readOnly: Bool) {
    // Instantiate the properties
    valueTextField = UITextField()
    valueStepper = UIStepper()
    numberOfDecimals = currentValue.components(separatedBy: ".").count > 1 ? currentValue.components(separatedBy: ".")[1].count : 1
    numericValue = Double(currentValue)!
    super.init(variableIndex: variableIndex, variableName: variableName, withParentView: parent)

    // Horizontal Stack View
    let horizontalStackView = UIStackView()
    horizontalStackView.axis = .horizontal
    horizontalStackView.alignment = .fill
    horizontalStackView.spacing = 15
    horizontalStackView.distribution = .fill
    horizontalStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    horizontalStackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    // Text Field
    valueTextField.text = stringValue
    valueTextField.textAlignment = .right
    valueTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    valueTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
    valueTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    #warning ("TODO: Enable interaction, change keyboard to numeric and add done button to keyboard")
    valueTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    valueTextField.rightView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ConfigFile.rightPadding, height: Int(valueTextField.frame.size.height)))
    valueTextField.rightViewMode = .always

    // Stepper
    valueStepper.value = numericValue
    valueStepper.stepValue = 0.1
    valueStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.stepperValueChanged(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    valueStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.test(sender:)), for: .allEditingEvents)
    valueStepper.isEnabled = !readOnly

    // Create the constraints
    constraints.append(NSLayoutConstraint(item: horizontalStackView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: stackView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

    horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(valueTextField)
    horizontalStackView.addArrangedSubview(valueStepper)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(horizontalStackView)
}

@objc private func stepperValueChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    numericValue = valueStepper.value
    let userInfo = [
        "VariableIndex": String(self.variableIndex),
        "NewValue": self.stringValue
    ]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .numericVariableChanged, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}

@objc private func test(sender: UIStepper) {
    print("Hi")
}
```

As you can see, I add the events with the lines

```
valueStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.stepperValueChanged(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
valueStepper.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.test(sender:)), for: .allEditingEvents)
```

I also tried using the `.allTouchEvents` argument on the second line but that didn't work.

All the views above the UIStepper have their `isUserInteractionEnabled` property set to `true`

During execution, I get feedback from the UIStepper when I press it (it changes color for a moment).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.valueChanged` event with a `UIStepper`, not `.touchUpInside` or `.allEditingEvents`.

Comment: @CarlosM. It is half of the problem at least. Pease note that no one could have known the other half of the issue based on the code you posted in your question.

Comment: you are right, I made the previous comment before I found the issue. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the one described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158000/uibutton-addtarget-selector-is-not-working)

Problem was that I didn't hold any reference to the object I was generating so it was being deinitialized immediately. I solved this by keeping a reference to it in the ViewController that holds it.