# iPad Popover Share Sheet in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit

I'm trying to show the iPad Popover share sheet (which uses `UIPopoverPresentationController`) from a SwiftUI `Button`. I've been able to get it to show but it only shows in the top left origin despite the `sourceView` and `sourceRect` being set differently.

Is there something else I need to set?

This is what the code currently produces,
[image: iPad Simulator showing Button and Text at bottom of iPad and the popover share sheet in the top left]

This is the code I have so far,

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State
    var label = "N/A"
    
    @State
    var buttonPos = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                          width: 0, height: 0)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{

            Spacer(minLength: 900)
            
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Button("Share"){
                    print("Share button is located at \(buttonPos)")
                    showShareSheetAtPopover()
                }.padding()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .frame(height: geometry.size.height)
                .background(Color.pink)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    buttonPos = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                    let localPos = geometry.frame(in: .local)
                    label = "Width: \(buttonPos.size) \n Global Pos: \(buttonPos.origin)  \n Local Pos: \(localPos.origin)"
                })
                
            }.background(Color.orange)
        
            Text(label)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.mint)
                .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                // don't truncate text
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }.background(Color.yellow)
    }
    
    func showShareSheetAtPopover(){
        let vc = (UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController)!
        
        let shareItem = ["Some Text to Share"]
        
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: shareItem,
            applicationActivities: nil)
        
        let onAnIPad = (ac.popoverPresentationController != nil)
        
        print( onAnIPad ? "On an iPad":"Not on an iPad" )
        
        if (onAnIPad){
            let popoverPos = buttonPos
            
            let ppc = ac.popoverPresentationController!
                        
            let sourceView = UIView(frame: popoverPos)
            print("Source View Frame \(sourceView.frame)")
            
            ppc.sourceView = sourceView
            ppc.sourceRect = popoverPos
            
            //vc.show(ac, sender: {})
            vc.present(ac, animated: true)
            
            print(ppc.frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView)

        }else{
            vc.show(ac, sender: {})

        }
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it kind of working by using a UIViewRepresentable to wrap a UIButton in the SwiftUI view and use that as the anchor point.

[image: Screenshot of the iPad simulator with the popover anchored to the UIButton]

Here is the updated code, it is not at all pretty or clean.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

final class MyUIButton: NSObject, UIViewRepresentable{
    
    @objc let action: () -> Void
    
    @objc var button: UIButton
    
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void){
        print("Creating button")
        
        self.action = action
        self.button = UIButton()
        super.init()
        self.button.setTitle("My Button", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        self.button.configuration = .filled()
        self.button.addTarget(self,
                         action: #selector(self.onButtonClick),
                         for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        print("Making button")

        return button
    }
    
    @objc func onButtonClick(){
        print("onClick")
        action()
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        print("Updating")
    }
    
}
```

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State
    var label = "N/A"
    
    @State
    var buttonPos = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                          width: 0, height: 0)
    
    // need to set it as a class variable otherwise the
    // selector does not get called
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158000/uibutton-addtarget-selector-is-not-working
    var myButton = MyUIButton(action:{
        print("Clicked!")
    })
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer(minLength: 900)
            
            self.myButton
                        
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Button("Share"){
                    print("Share button is located at \(buttonPos)")
                    showShareSheetAtPopover()
                }.padding()
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
                .frame(height: 40)
                .background(Color.pink)
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    buttonPos = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                    let localPos = geometry.frame(in: .local)
                    label = "Width: \(buttonPos.size) \n Global Pos: \(buttonPos.origin)  \n Local Pos: \(localPos.origin)"
                })
                
            }.background(Color.orange)
            
            Spacer(minLength: 50)

            Text(label)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.mint)
                .frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                // don't truncate text
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }.background(Color.yellow)
    }
    
    func showShareSheetAtPopover(){
        let vc = (UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController)!
        
        let shareItem = ["Some Text to Share"]
        
        let ac = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: shareItem,
            applicationActivities: nil)
        
        let onAnIPad = (ac.popoverPresentationController != nil)
        
        print( onAnIPad ? "On an iPad":"Not on an iPad" )
        
        if (onAnIPad){
            let popoverPos = buttonPos
            
            let ppc = ac.popoverPresentationController!
                        
            let sourceView = UIView(frame: popoverPos)
            print("Source View Frame \(sourceView.frame)")
            
            ppc.sourceView = myButton.button
            //ppc.sourceRect = popoverPos
            
            //vc.show(ac, sender: {})
            vc.present(ac, animated: true)
            
            print(ppc.frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView)

        }else{
            vc.show(ac, sender: {})

        }
        

    }
}
```